# TYPO3 Ext:form Checkbox Label with Link inside

Tags: forms, checkbox, yaml, typo3-9.x

I'm using the latest `TYPO3 9.5.13` and made an contact form with the new form system extension: `form`

I need a checkbox before Submit button, f.e. "I've read the privacy policy .. "
I've found this extension, because this is not working out of the box.
https://github.com/tritum/form_element_linked_checkbox (installed via composer the latest master 1.1.0)

I can't create a Text like this: "Yes, I've read the [privacy policy](https://typo3.org) and blahablah .." The link is always at the end of the label. I've made it like they shown in the  description of the extension `form-element-linked-checkbox`. Have I forget something? Here's my `YAML`

```
  -
    type: LinkedCheckbox
    identifier: linkedcheckbox-1
    label: ' Ja, ich habe die %s gelesen und bin mit der Verarbeitung meiner Daten einverstanden.'
    properties:
      pageUid: '17'
      linkText: Datenschutzhinweise
      elementDescription:
      fluidAdditionalAttributes:
        required: required
    validators:
      -
        identifier: NotEmpty
```

my result in frontend:

[image: frontend ext:form linked checkbox]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was blind!!! Damn!
Sorry, for my stupid error. I forgot the `' '` at labelText, see below:

```
  -
    type: LinkedCheckbox
    identifier: linkedcheckbox-1
    label: ' Ja, ich habe die %s gelesen und bin mit der Verarbeitung meiner Daten einverstanden.'
    properties:
      pageUid: '17'
      linkText: 'Datenschutzhinweise'
      elementDescription:
      fluidAdditionalAttributes:
        required: required
    validators:
      -
        identifier: NotEmpty
```